# How to connect 3 bars end to end in Webots?

Tags: webots

I am trying to build a tensegrity structure in Webots, where a fundamental structural feature is 2 bars and a linear spring connecting end to end to form a triangle. Is there any way to build such a structure?

To be more specific, I built a 2-bar structure first like this:
[2-bar structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zmXD.png). Its root node is "Robot" and it is followed by a "Transform" node representing the first bar, and then a "HingeJoint" node. The endpoint of the "HingeJoint" node is a "Solid" node for the second bar. I would like to have a passive joint between these two bars so I added a position sensor instead of motor for device. The node structure can be depicted here: [node info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUlws.png).

The first issue is the 2-bar structure seems rigid at the joint.

The second question is can I add a linear spring relationship between the ends of these 2 bars, so that it will be like a triangle, where 2 edges are rigid bars and the third edge is a linear spring?

Thanks,
Keran

Comment: Please, add more details in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your first issue, what you did looks correct, but you have to make sure that you did set the bounding-object and physics attribute of the Solid in the endPoint field of the joint.

About the spring, you will have to add a SliderJoint node in the children field of your second Solid and use the Solidreference mechanism to connect to the root node:
https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/solidreference